# Default js included in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

When creating a new Rails application, it is automatically supplied with several quite large js files. In the application layout, by default, all of them are loaded into the page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

I was wondering, isn't loading all those javascripts can make the site possibly mush slower?
And if so, where can I change the definition of `:defaults`? Or should I just include the ones I need and remove the code line mentioned above?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In config/application.rb

```
# JavaScript files you want as :defaults (application.js is always included).
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery.js rails.js)
```

Using `:defaults` is not mandatory in any way. If you are worried about performance you should read at least the caching part from `javascript_include_tag` docs:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag